# Refactor complex IQueryable LINQ into sub methods

Tags: linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, iqueryable

We have inherited a solution made by another developer where we have a method that generates a complex product structure for an api call. The model (Product) here is fetched from Entity Framework, through an IQueryable and the DTO is generated in one gigantic LINQ statement that span some 230 lines of code, making it neigh impossible to debug.
We are running on EF Core 3.1.3 just FYI.

I want to refactor this code to ensure we have a better understanding of what may go wrong in the code, but I seem to run into an issue that may reside with my understanding of how to work with IQueryables.

To keep it simple I have taken the simplest part of the code as an example. The rest is omitted for readability.

```
private async Task<List<HomePageProductModel>> FindProducts(IQueryable<Data.Entities.Product> products, string priceBehaviour = "DefaultPrice")
        {
            var productModel = products.Select(p => new HomePageProductModel
            {
                Id = p.ProductId,
                Segment = p.Segment.Name,
                StartDate = p.StartDate,
                EndDate = p.EndDate,
                Type = p.ProductType.Name,
                Title = p.Title,
                Teaser = p.Teaser,
                Description = p.Description,
                TermsAndConditionsLink = p.Prices.SelectMany(p => p.PriceBehaviours.Where(p => p.PriceBehaviourType.Name == "TermsAndConditionsUrl")).Select(p => p.PriceBehaviourType.Value).FirstOrDefault(),
```

I want to extract the part that generates the TermsAndConditionsLink. My first goto, was to just extract everything as a method and then let that do the same LINQ selectMany as such

```
TermsAndConditionsLink = TermsAndConditionsLink(p)


private static string TermsAndConditionsLink(Product p)
{
    return p.Prices.SelectMany(p => p.PriceBehaviours.Where(p => p.PriceBehaviourType.Name == "TermsAndConditionsUrl")).Select(p => p.PriceBehaviourType.Value).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Which compiles, but throws a NullRefence on p.PriceBehaviours, because the List is now nolonger IQueryable, but is a list due to how the model is generated and the PriceBehaviours are not included anymore.

I did get it working after fiddling with it for an hour or so, but I am unsure whether I now have created multiple iterations over the same object or whether it is performance wise ok to do as I have done.

```
TermsAndConditionsLink = GetTermsAndConditionsLink(products)

private static string GetTermsAndConditionsLink(IQueryable<Product> product)
{
     return product.SelectMany(pr => pr.Prices).SelectMany(p => p.PriceBehaviours.Where(p => p.PriceBehaviourType.Name == "TermsAndConditionsUrl")).Select(p => p.PriceBehaviourType.Value).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

The model is as follows (heavily reduced to only what is relavant):

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public List<Price> Prices { get; set; }
}

public class Price
{
    public int PriceId { get; set; }
    public List<PriceBehaviour> PriceBehaviours { get; set; }
}

public class PriceBehaviour // relation
{
    public int PriceBehaviourId { get; set; }
    public Price Price { get; set; }
    public PriceBehaviourType PriceBehaviourType { get; set; }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on making it better or is what I have achieved here, performance wise ok?

Comment: Consider using [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) to create embeddable query pieces.

Comment: Thanks for you swift answer! I have a few urgent tasks, but will try this out once they're done and post my findings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot extract `TermsAndConditionsLink` in that way. EF can not look into method body and create needed query.
There are third party extensions for such task: https://github.com/axelheer/nein-linq

So you method should be rewritten in the following way:

```cs
[InjectLambda]
private static string TermsAndConditionsLink(Product p)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private static Expression<Func<Product, string>> TermsAndConditionsLink()
{
    return p => p.Prices.SelectMany(p => p.PriceBehaviours
          .Where(p => p.PriceBehaviourType.Name == "TermsAndConditionsUrl"))
       .Select(p => p.PriceBehaviourType.Value)
       .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

And do not forget to call `.ToInjectable()` at the top of the query.

Also similar result you can achieve with another library https://github.com/hazzik/DelegateDecompiler

Comment: Thanks for you swift answer! I have a few urgent tasks, but will try this out once they're done and post my findings!

Comment: Thanks for your answer again! I got back to my refactoring task today and I went with your approach and it works great! I have accepted your answer.